# How to create a custom pipe that receives an object as a filter in angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm struggling to apply a pipe that receives an object as a parameter for filtering. Here I let the code i'm working on:

```
import { IProductFilter } from 'app/helpers/filters';
import { IProduct } from './../../domain/product';
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
    name: 'productFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: IProduct[], filterBy: IProductFilter): IProduct[] {

        return value.filter((product: IProduct) => {
            return ((product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.productName.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 || product.productName) &&
                (product.productCode.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.productCode.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 || product.productCode) && 
                (product.releaseDate.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.releaseDate.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 || product.releaseDate) &&
                (product.price === filterBy.price || product.price) &&
                (product.starRating === filterBy.rating || product.starRating))
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my html template

```
<tr *ngFor='let product of products | productFilter:productCriteria' (click)="viewDetails(product.productId)">
                        <td>
                            <label>{{ product.productName }}</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>{{ product.productCode }}</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>{{ product.releaseDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>{{ product.price | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2' }}</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>{{ product.starRating }}</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a md-button routerLink="." (click)='openModal(2, product)' role="button"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit"></i></a>
                            <a md-button routerLink="." (click)='removeProduct(product.productId)' role="button"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Remove"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

this isn't filtering my list. But if I just apply only one property of my Interface the filter works ok.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats in IProduct and IProductFilter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a pipe to filter or sort is not recommended as per the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Instead, consider building the sorting or filtering in the component class.

Here is an example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html'
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

    _listFilter: string;
    get listFilter(): string {
        return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        this.filteredProducts = this.listFilter ? this.performFilter(this.listFilter) : this.products;
    }

    filteredProducts: IProduct[];
    products: IProduct[] = [];

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {

    }

    performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
              product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productService.getProducts()
                .subscribe(products => {
                    this.products = products;
                    this.filteredProducts = this.products;
                },
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

And let's take a look at your filtering logic:

```
return value.filter((product: IProduct) => {
    return ((product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.productName.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 || product.productName) &&
        (product.productCode.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.productCode.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 || product.productCode) && 
        (product.releaseDate.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.releaseDate.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 || product.releaseDate) &&
        (product.price === filterBy.price || product.price) &&
        (product.starRating === filterBy.rating || product.starRating))
});
```

Each of these lines:

```
(product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase()
       .indexOf(filterBy.productName.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 
   || product.productName)
```

Is basically saying:

1) If the lower case product name contains the characters defined in the lower case filterBy product name

2) OR the productName is set

3) THEN include the product in the filtered list.

So as long as all of the properties are set, it will include the items in the list (and not filter them out).

Try something like this instead:

```
return value.filter((product: IProduct) => 
   (filterBy.productName ?
    product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.productName.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 :
    true) &&
   (filterBy.productCode ?
    product.productCode.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.productCode.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 :
    true) && ...
```

Comment: how would the html go with this? I can't figure it out.

Comment: 'let product of filteredProducts'

Comment: I did it that way and worked correctly, thanks. Off topic, i'm watching your course of angular 2 in pluralsight, it's very nice, concise and get me into angular 2. Thx

Comment: Hi. The documentation was updated at some time between 2020/05/07 and 2020/09/23, removing the mentioned appendix. However, I've found no information regarding this removal, and the Angular 11 release info does not reflect anything about it either.

Is it still discouraged to use a pipe to filter items in Angular 11?

Comment: Yes, it is still discouraged. This was originally important in the documentation because in AngularJS (v1) there was a filter pipe and it was necessary to explain why there wasn't one in Angular v2. Over time, this was thought to be less important as fewer are coming from v1. But it is still definitely discouraged.